# How to install 'kompare' on a mac?

Tags: mac, homebrew

I have a MacBook Air and am having trouble installing the linux tool 'kompare'. I tried to install it with `brew`, but it did not work as expected:

```
>brew install kompare
Error: No available formula with the name "kompare" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

So is there a magic 'formula' with which this install works? I thought that 'brew' is the `apt install` equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Kompare is not available for macOS. You can use Apple's FileMerge (a separate app but downloaded as part of [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)), or any other 3rd party alternatives:

- [Graphical multiple file-pair comparison on Mac OS 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11849918/1549818)

Answer (score 0):

brew is not the only one on mac. the old good MacPorts works well enough

https://www.macports.org

install macports and enter this command:

**$ sudo port install kompare**

it downloads all dependencies on your mac and builds & installs the app